# How to programmatically know whether Firebase Realtime database limit (100 simultaneous connection) is reached?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display a text or toast to the user saying to wait for some time when the connection limits are exceeded.

How to find out that the maximum allowed limit of connections to Firebase Realtime database is exceeded? Is there some specific return value when the 101th connection is trying to connect or something?

Comment: I know that not every developer has the money to buy expensive services etc.. But as a rule of thumb, use the best tools, money can buy. If you upload your app to the store, that needs you to at least spend $25 on your dev account. And so does the Firebase Flame plan. It is still limited (100k connections, not 100), so you do not have to worry exceed anything. And you don't have to write hacky code to display bad UX wise Dialogs, telling the user to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main question should be, what happens when we reach the limit of `concurrent connections`? Talking about `concurrent connections` it means the `number of writes per seconds`.

At that moment, the Firebase database will start to queue up the number of writes that cannot be written on the disk straight away. With other words, Firebase biulds a `buffer of the pendings write operations`. If the write volum goes down, it will start caching up with the buffer.

The answer to your question, is no, there is no way to know programmatically  whether Firebase realtime database reaches the limit. There is no method that has as a return value the maximum number of connections. But, there is although a workaroung in which you can attach a `CompletionListener`. If you'll see that the time between when you start the write operation and when it completes `goes up`, it means that you're buffered (queued). This is how you can know when the 100 simultaneous connection is reached.

Comment: Suppose if the 101th person is trying to connect . Then will the person be able to establish a connection . I mean can the 101th person can type the message and press send , the will the message be send from the device and be stored in firebase buffer. Will that cached message be stored in buffer untill someone disconnects and then the message is now stored in realtime db and reaches all ??

Comment: The problem is not about establishing a connection. The user will be connected for sure. And yes, the user will be able to type the message and press send and the message will be sent directly in the queue. When a user disconnects, the message will be for sure written in the cached database but this has nothing to do with what is happening online, on Firebase server. But remember, when you'll reach the maximum number of writes per second, it doesn't mean that you'll not be able to use Firebase database anymore. You'll be able to use the database with a delay.

Comment: That helps . Thanks